# Como receber headers no express enviados pelo axios no react.js

Tags: node.js, express.js, http-request, http-headers, axios

Meu front envia requisições com o axios para API node express dessa forma:

```
class ServiceRequest {

  constructor() {
    this.api = axios.create({
      baseURL: URL_BASE,
      timeout: 1000,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'x-access-token': 'dgwtvretvrerv',
        'x-access-key': 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1'
      }
    });
  }

  create( url, object ) {
    return new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
      this.api.post( url, object )
         .then( response => response.status === 200 ? resolve( response.data ) : reject( response.data ) )
         .catch( error => reject( error.request.response ) );
    });
  }
}
```

Mas em minha API node express eu não consigo receber esses valores. Meu cabecalho vem dessa forma:

```
{ host: 'localhost:1234',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  'access-control-request-method': 'POST',
  origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.110 Safari/537.36',
  dnt: '1',
  'access-control-request-headers': 'x-access-key,x-access-token',
  accept: '*/*',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
  'accept-language': 'pt-BR,pt;q=0.9' }
```

Quando tento `console.log(req.headers['x-access-key'])` ele imprime um `undefined`.

Notei também que `req.method` esta vindo como `OPTIONS`, mas eu estou usando `POST`!

Alguém poderia me ajudar a receber / enviar os cabeçalhos de forma correta?

//edit

Tenho esse middleware que uso em `app.use()` no meu servidor

```
const allowCrossDomain = (req, res, next) => {  
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');

  next();
};
```

Comment: Edita sua pergunta adicionando o trecho do código onde você faz a chamada ao Express

Comment: Acho que não está com problemas lá, pois quando testo com o Postman ela funciona de boas... Consigo acessar o cabeçalho na boa.

Answer (score 1):

Você está enviando essa requisição através do mesmo website que oferece esse serviço?

Quando uma requisição de origem cruzada do tipo POST, PUT or PATCH é enviada por um navegador, o navegador envia primeiro uma requisição do tipo OPTIONS por motivos de segurança.

O servidor deve então responder enviando o header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` contendo o endereço do seu website (ou então `*`) para autorizar o navegador a enviar o POST propriamente dito.

Comment: Cliente e API estão em `http://localhost`, mas ambos têm seus próprios servidores rodando em portas diferentes que são a `3000` e `1234` respectivamente.

Answer (score 0):

Você deve habilitar no CORS o cabeçalho `x-access-token`:

```
const allowCrossDomain = (req, res, next) => {  
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, x-access-key');

  next();
};
```